# Select features by correlation with label in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, list

I have a dataframe of the form:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : [1,2,3],
                    'B' : [4,5,6],
                    'label' : [1.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                 })
```

And I first select only the features that have a correlation above a threshold to the `'label'` column.

```
cor = df.corr()
cor_target = abs(cor["label"])
relevant_features = cor_target[cor_target>0.05]
```

How can I use the `relevant_features` object to filter out a new dataframe, say `df2` from `df`, that only has those features in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `.loc`:

```
cor = df.corr()
cor_target = abs(cor["label"])
relevant_features = cor_target[cor_target>0.05]
df2 = df.loc[:, relevant_features.index]
```

Comment: I believe `df.loc[:, relevant_features.index]` can just be `df[relevent_features.index]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer one liner

```py
out = df[cor["label"].abs().gt(0.5).loc[lambda s: s].index]
```

```
print(out)

   label
0    1.0
1    0.0
2    1.0
```